# Boas práticas para armazenar logs

Tags: sql, log

- Quais informações devem ser armazenadas?
- É uma boa prática usar `TRIGGER` no **banco de dados** para armazenamento de logs ou via código é algo mais seguro e de fácil manutenção?

Comment: A utilização de trigger garante que que tudo será registrado. Via código você terá que garantir que toda e qualquer aplicação que utilize o banco de dados faça o devido registro o que, em minha opinião, só é possível em bancos e aplicações minúsculas.

Comment: As 2 formas são validas, e as 2 oferecem vantagens e desvantagens. Por banco de dados dificulta na manutenção pois se não tiver uma boa documentação essa lógica acaba sendo perdida ou muito dificil de achar. Mas se for no código, tem que ser muito bem feita e abranger todas as situações.

Comment: @Guerra eu sei, mais quais são elas?

Comment: É por essa que o Hibernate Envers vem muito a calhar. Mas isso só se você estiver usando Java com Hibernate / JPA. O Hibernate Envers permite você auditar / logar somente entidades que você define e tudo de forma automática.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger existe um consumo extra do SQL, porque ele ficará monitorando tudo, então a um overload em todos os processos. Não recomendo.
Claro que desenvolver um software externo é melhor, porém desde que você possa desenvolver, conheça uma linguagem, etc. Mas se for possível opte pelo software externo no lugar de Trigger.
OBS: Trigger e Cursor em MSSQL são 2 coisas que consomem muitos recursos, evite utiliza-los sempre.

Sobre o que armazenar? não entendi sua pergunta, isso depende de você, o que você acha que é importante? é de algum software que estamos falando?
Você deve lembrar de alguns fatores:

- Essa informação é importante? Se sim, como devo armazena-la? (varchar, int, etc)
- Durante quanto tempo devo armazenar a informação ? Se a informação tem uma vida útil, ou seja, depois de X tempo não servirá para mais nada, então criar uma ferramenta de expurgo para remover informações antigas.
- Qual será o tamanho dessa tabela, cada campo existe seu consumo, ex: int=8bytes, varchar consome em bytes o próprio tamanho, nvarchar a um overload de +1bytes por campo., somou todas as colunas, multiplique pela quantidade de registros, assim poderá saber qual o tamanho, 20mb, 200mb, 2gb por dia, semana, mês.
- Outra dica, tem que se pensar melhor, se é apenas um log, imagino que seja uma auditoria de tudo o que o usuário estiver fazendo, então evite criar índices nessa tabela, ou pense bem antes de criar, toda vez que você tiver um índice existe um consumo para inserir registros.

Caso queira especifique melhor, mostre um exemplo da tabela.

Answer (score 7):

As boas práticas de logging seguem dois princípios base:

1. Um log deve ser eficiente
2. Um log deve ser seguro

**Eficiência de um log**

O log deve conter valores verbosos, por exemplo chave=valor (name="john doe"), de forma a que possa ser lido por um humano. Deve-se evitar o registo de informação binária em logs.

Deve-se registar sempre o timestamp em todos os eventos. A data/hora correcta é essencial para se perceber se algo correu mal.

Deve-se usar Unique ID's nos vários eventos/transacções. O uso de UID, e o seu registo em log, permite identificar de forma unívoca um registo. É também muito útil em processos de debug.

Como princípio base deve ser guardada a seguinte informação:

- Who (quem)
- What (o quê)
- When (quando)
- Where (onde)

**Segurança de um log**

Um log para ser seguro, deve ser assegurado **idealmente** a nível da base de dados. Quando o logging é assegurado através de programação, existe a possibilidade do programador esquecer-se de registar em log um determinado evento. Se o log for assegurado ao nível da base de dados, é assegurado de forma nativa o registo de todos os eventos.

Um log deve seguir o princípio de WORM (Write Once Read Many).

Um log deve ter um checksum/hash de forma a que possa ser avaliada a sua coerência.

Idealmente, o log deve ser guardado off-site (noutra máquina) de forma a que possa comparado retrospectivamente com o log "original".

*Disclamer*: As boas práticas que aqui indico adequam-se a aplicações de negócio críticas.

*just my 2 cents*

Answer (score 3):

Todas as maneiras estão corretas, no entanto a medida que a aplicação crescer o seu banco vai inflar e suas tabelas de auditoria vão ficar gigantes e lentas.

Em varias aplicações pelas quais trabalhei que possuíam auditoria, **todas** acabavam tendo este mesmo problema. A principio parece uma boa ideia mas a longo prazo acaba se tornando uma baita dor de cabeça.

Em novas aplicações procuro abstrair esse problema (não somente esse tipo de problema, mas também outros cuja a aplicação não tem responsabilidade de lidar) usando um Saas. Essa é uma ótima solução pois você vai deixar uma corporação especializada em auditoria resolver o seu problema. Simplesmente você terá que consumir uma API que eles irão lhe disponibilizar, e eles irão resolver o seu problema. Alem disso, todos os dados de auditoria irão ficar fora do seu banco de dados, pois estarão dentro deste serviço e será responsabilidade deles resolver problemas de lentidão etc, e você irá se concentrar no que é importante, a sua regra de negocio.

Eu recomendo você utilizar o [AuditingShip](http://auditingship.com), Saas de auditoria. Algumas empresas já estão utilizando ele e estão gostando muito. Algumas vantagens:

- é rápido de fazer um "Hello Word", questão de 5 minutos ou menos;
- você consegue utilizar com **qualquer linguagem** que consuma REST, ele ate mostra alguns exemplos com JavaScript e Ruby;
- documentação simples e dinâmica.

Answer (score 1):

Depende um pouco da tecnologia que você está usando mas o @guerra está certo.

Por trigger dificulta a manutenção e você terá que implementar a trigger em n tabelas. Não é prático se você tiver muitas tabelas e de um modo geral triggers não facilitam a manutenção e depuração. Por outro lado é um método rápido e prático se você tiver poucas tabelas sendo auditadas, por exemplo se você só está auditando uma tabela de logons.
Outra vantagem é não ter que mexer em códigos legados ou de terceiros.

Por código seria o "mais correto" do ponto de vista de OO quando você está criando um sistema. Você simplesmente pode criar uma classe Auditable por exemplo e herdar suas classes de acesso ao BD dessa classe, automatizando o processo de auditoria, reusando código e centralizando a manutenção dessa funcionalidade nessa classe. Pode usar extension methods ou qualquer coisa do gênero com o mesmo objetivo.

Se você usa .Net você pode usar o Log4Nnet por exemplo que é um framework que já te automatiza boa parte do trabalho de criar logs de suas aplicações. Procure ver se a tecnologia que você usa já não possui alguma ferramenta semelhante.